# My HTML5 form displays inline and without line breaks

Tags: forms, html

I'm doing this HTML5 form, but when I check it on the browser (running it locally) it displays the label next to the input space next to le label and so.
heres the code:

```
<form>      
    <label for="name">Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ingresa tu Nombre" required />
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu e-mail " required  />
    <label for="message">Mensage:</label>
    <textarea id="message" placeholder="Ingresa tu Mensaje" required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Envia tu mensage" >
</form>
```

should I use `<br />`? I already checked on other web pages and they dont use it
thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As Kolink pointed out, the form displays *inline* as all the elements inside it are *inline*.

**You shouldn't be using `<br/>` or `<p>` as they are not intended for that purpose** (*You shouldn't be using a toothbrush to clean a toilet*). Better use a `<ul>` with `<li>` for each field. This makes sense as the form is nothing but a **list** of fields.

The mark-up would be like this:

```
<form>
 <ul>
   <li>
     <label for="something">some label</label>
     <input id="something" />
   </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can go ahead and use `<div>` as well (but not `<p>`).

Answer (score 2):

Well, `<label>` is inline, `<input>` is inline, `<textarea>` is inline...

If all your elements are inline, of course your overall form will be.

Try using the `<br />` tag, or maybe `<p>...</p>`.

Comment: You can, or you can use `<p>...</p>` which does it for you.

Comment: A form isn't really comprised of paragraphs. A div tag would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Kolink is correct. Another way to address this is to add

```
display: block;
```

to all input and label elements using CSS.